# If there is a class and a variable by the same name in the same scope, how to specify the class?

Tags: c++

picture time!

```
struct my_struct {
                ___________ class name (A)
               ↓
    struct pineapple {};
    pineapple pineapple;
                 ↑______________ variable name (B)

                   ____________ seems to be referring to B instead of A
                  ↓
    my_struct(pineapple pineapple) {
        this->pineapple = pineapple;
    }
};
```

So there is a class and a variable sharing the same name. While this normally doesn't bother c++, in case of function parameters(such as the constructor there), it seems to prefer the name of the local variable over the class.

Is there a way to specify that I mean the class and not the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you do that to yourself?

Anyhow, you can use the [elaborated type specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier) to disambiguate:

```
struct my_struct {
    struct pineapple {};
    pineapple pineapple;

    my_struct(struct pineapple pineapple) {
              ^^^^^^
        this->pineapple = pineapple;
    }
};
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QuCaMeAzGPP6znpL)

That being said, this is really weird design, I'd avoid it.

Comment: as to the why - all the members of pineapple are a subgroup of my_struct members that I had to stick in a nested struct because pineapple needs to inherit and implement a 3rd party ui class. Since I couldn't find a decent synonym for a pineapple, my other option was to add underscores or something to one of the names.. but I didn't like how it looked  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: use ananas, please. Or pineapple_t (or _v). Naming things is hard, I know, but not to the point where you have to reuse names in the same scope :P